# Android 3.x emulator app launcher not working

Tags: android, emulation, android-3.0-honeycomb

I'm trying to check how a web page is displayed in the Android emulator browser, but seems that I'm out of luck today.
I just installed the new API 13 AVD, launched it with WXGA resolution and realised that it was unusable (it hanged).

Then I edited the configuration and now it is only 640x480. The GUI has changed a little, but still it hangs when I try to open the applications launcher (to find the browser icon). Only the notifications slider works, but is really slow.

How can I open the browser?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to do it. Here's what I've done:

- In Android SDK and AVD manager, increased hw.RamSize and vm.heapSize
- The portrait orientation (CTRL+F11) seems a bit more responsive than the landscape one.
- Sometimes playing with F4 (end call button) helps unfreezing the GUI.

But in general, I've noticed hangs, GUI unresponsiveness, and when it works it is really slow. Seems that it is something related to the screen size. Or maybe it needs a ton of RAM.