# Back arrow missing in my Activity

Tags: android

I have created 2 activity in my android application. 2nd activity will launch from first activity button click. activity launches 
but I can not see back arrow. I have to use hardware button to go back to main activity.

This is my second activity xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.xxxxxxx.widget.MonthView
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

How to get the back arrow button on header of second activity?

I am using java code to launch as follow

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CalendarActivity.class);
 getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Unlike the iOS platform, Android does not have the back button. If you absolutely must have one, you will have to explicitly add one.

Comment: Do you mean the < symbol in the action bar at the left of the icon ?

Comment: you should give them this link http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html

Comment: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To display the "<" you should be using :

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

than, to intercept the "Home Button" press :

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId()==android.R.id.home){
        finish();//finish your activity
    }
    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}
```

Comment: This is actually not the correct way to implement onMenuItemSelected.  

The problem here is that since you just call finish, if the parent activity is not already running, you just close this activity and dont actually go "up".

Rather than just finishing your activity, you should launch the activity "above" it in your applications hierarchy using the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP flag.  What this will do is: If there is already an instance of that activity running, it will just pop off any activities above it, and if not, it will create it.

Comment: NO. This is the correct way. If you navigate in your App using Activities, when you will call `finish()` even if the previous `Activity` was destroyed it will be re-created.

Comment: Not if your activity was launched from another task.  For example if you're writing an email app, and you write a compose activity. If that compose activity is launched from the browser, via a share intent, pressing the "up" affordance will just close compose and go to [undefined location]

Comment: If you plan on running the app on Android 2.x and 3.x (e.g. with ActionbarSherlock) you should override `onOptionsItemSelected()`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557409/android-3-x-emulator-app-launcher-not-working

Answer (score 0):

in Android, the back button is a hardware button and not a View in the top of the screen such as in the iPhone development world.

no need for a back button, just click the hardware back button.

Comment: its client requirement :( they want consistency in both iOS and Android app

Comment: well then... I think you need to create an `ActionBar` with a custom back button

Comment: Ah, the consistency fallacy ;)  a.  It's far more important to have consistency amongst apps on the same device, Android->Android or iOS->iOS, not iOS->Android and b.  What percentage of their users do they believe will use the same app on iOS and Android?  That's why iOS has a navigation controller and Android has the ActionBar.